# Apache redirect all files

Tags: php, apache

How to rewrite every URI to the index.php?

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

this rewrites only files in current directory, so example.org/folder does not rewrite.

Comment: my code is work, I've found if I have a folder with .htaccess -     RewriteRule .* - [F] then instead of redirect, it will give 403 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that rule is in an htaccess file in your document root, then it will redirect everything. Instead of `.`, it should be `.*`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: @ArtDesire with just the `.` it means there *must be* at least 1 character, whereas `.*` means *zero or more*. URI's have the leading slash stripped off so when the request is just `/`, it's actually an empty string after the slash is removed so `.` wouldn't match it

Comment: but without redirect, index.php will anyway execute.